# I think I deleted Windows 7 when trying to install Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot, 11.10, wine, data-recovery

What happened is I attempted to download and install the operating system **Ubuntu 11.10** on my computer.

I had planned to choose which operating system to boot, but there were a few options on the website:

- install along with "windows" which is what I wanted to do
- install from a CD or usb

After I installed it I noticed that I could not boot using Windows, all the folders, files and programs for **Windows 7** could be found under Ubuntu, but I couldn't run any of them using ***wine***.

I want to know if I removed the operating system **Windows**, if I could use it again if I needed it, and how to operate the wine application.

To make clear in the page I chose the option to install the usb and it says **Not run with Windows**.

Answer (score 2):

**NO YOU ARE NOT**

Follow these steps to recover your windows instalation!!!

Step1

```
Turn On your computer.
Go to bios.
Set the boot media to CD/DVD
Put the windows 7 DVD(or recovery disk) in to the drive.
Boot from the DVD
```

Step2

```
Start windows repair(if you use windows 7 DVD or if you are using recovery it will automatically show repairing option)
Allow the utility to repair startup.
If utility found a error and fixed it reboot the machine and enjoy!!
```

If it failed.. follow step 3.

Step3

```
Open command prompt in recovery mode.
Type diskpart hit enter
Then type list disk hit enter
Then select your disk(you can find it by size) - use select disk x to select the disk. Replace x by relevant number.
Then type list part hit enter.
Then select primary disk with mb in size(not in gb) - use select part x to select the part. Hit enter.
Then type active hit enter.
Close the command prompt and again run the startup recovery tool.
```

Enjoy!!!

Comment: By this you will only be able to boot to Ubuntu again by reinstalling Grub.

Comment: Windows Setup reinstalls Grub? Never :D. But this will agin boot ur computer directly in to the windows.

Comment: Already I found the problem, to start windows 7 only reinstalled it, and the programs of windows, to traverse them in wine, since particioné the alone disc I copied the programs to the disc that it uses ubuntu and to change the permissions and I list, already I can use my PC.